# Amplification of a speech signal in the recorded audio

Tags: audio, speech-processing, audio-processing

I have recorded an audio.

I dont know how it happened that only one sided speech is recorded and the other speech is recorded with a very low sound. Is there any solution to amplify the other side signal.  I have tried to amplify with AVS software but its also ampliying the noise in the audio.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried converting (downmixing) to mono? This will eliminate low amplitude channel, and will not add noise either, yet you will lose the stereo image (if that was important for the speech). Otherwise apply some noise reduction before amplifying the low amplitude channel.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more how I can convert the audio to (downmixing) to mono. Is there any good software tool you suggest to do that.

Comment: Well, **Audacity** (free & open-source) will make it...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend amplifying the low signal because that will increase noise significantly. As was pointed out above, it's better to downmix to mono.

Open your recording in a DAW (e.g. Audacity), delete the quiet channel, then copy the loud signal into the deleted channel. Voila!

Comment: I opened the recording in the Audacity. There are two channels I converted downmix to mono by selecing Split Stereo to mono. After that I removed the signal below. Then exported the remaining one as audio file which still have both the wanted and unwanted speech signals.  how to identify the quite channel here as both of the channel are having wanted and unwanted signals.

Comment: In Audacity, you can mute each channel one by one and listen to it to identify the quiet signal. You can also visually inspect the waveforms (the louder signal will have "more" content). After you've deleted the quiet signal (for example, let's say it's the Left channel), make sure you copy the loud signal to the Left channel before exporting.